# How to run table and print a specific key

Tags: lua, lua-table

I have a table:

```
employee = {
             name = "John", age = 30,
             name = "George", age = 35
           }
```

Now, I want to run the whole table, and if the name "George" is found, then the appropriate age to be printed. How can I do this? From what I searched I found that you can run a list with the code `for k, v in pairs(employee) do` but I don't know how to continue from there.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your table will need to be restructured to start off with.

```
employee = {
    {name = "John", age = 30},
    {name = "George", age = 35},
}
```

This will allow the age to always match up with the name. Then you could run:

```
for _,v in ipairs(employee) do
    if v.name == "George" then
        return v.age
    end
end
```

You can even create it as a function so you can check whatever name you want:

```
function find_age(n)
  for _,v in ipairs(employee) do
      if v.name == n then
          return v.age
      end
  end
end
```

Of course, this will return the age of every `n` in the table, though.

**Updated for comment**

You can do it with a function as well.

```
function add_employee(n,a)
  table.insert(employee, {name = n, age = a})
end
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer! One last quick question I got, is how can I programatically add another employee on the above list? For example add a third one with name "Paul" and age "33". I write employee[3].name = "Paul" but this gives a nil value... Works fine for indeces 1-2 though but that is for editing the previous ones... Thanks and sorry for bothering you

Comment: Updated my answer for your question, and never apologize for bothering people! :)